# Hibernate doesn't do batch inserts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of entities that I save in the database using the saveAll method. Hibernate does not use BatchInsert by default, but I need it. I changed the GeneratedValuy strategy from Identity on the SEQUENCE and put in the Yaml file: jdbc.batch_size: 25 but that didn't help, multiple insert requests are still being made. When displaying statistics in Hibernate, I see that 3 batches are done, but if you look at the SQL queries, the batches are not executed at all.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Question {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "text")
private String text;

@Column(name = "is_question_with_text_answer")
private boolean isQuestionWithTextAnswer;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private ActualQuiz actualQuiz;
}
```

Service method:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void saveQuestions(List<QuestionRequestDTO> questionsDTO) {
    var actualQuiz = actualQuizService.findActualQuiz();
    var questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    for (QuestionRequestDTO question : questionsDTO) {
        questionList.add(Question.builder()
                .text(question.getQuestion())
                .isQuestionWithTextAnswer(question.isQuestionWithTextAnswer())
                .actualQuiz(actualQuiz)
                .build());
    }
    questionRepository.saveAll(questionList);
}
```

Hibernate statistic:

```
275400 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
954100 nanoseconds spent preparing 12 JDBC statements;
4377100 nanoseconds spent executing 9 JDBC statements;
2998100 nanoseconds spent executing 3 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
32059500 nanoseconds spent executing 3 flushes (flushing a total of 17 entities and 0 collections);
476700 nanoseconds spent executing 7 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 7 entities and 7 collections)
```

Sql queries:

```
Hibernate: insert into questions (actual_quiz_id,is_question_with_text_answer,text,id) values (?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: insert into questions (actual_quiz_id,is_question_with_text_answer,text,id) values (?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: insert into questions (actual_quiz_id,is_question_with_text_answer,text,id) values (?,?,?,?)
```

My configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: 
    password: 
    url: jdbc:postgresql://dbUrl:5432/quiz_bot
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 25
          order_inserts: true
          order_updates: true
        generate_statistics: true
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml
```

Also i tried to add ?reWriteBatchedInserts=true after dbUrl, it doen't help.

Comment: Which database are you using? HIbernate utilizes the driver, and could be that hibernate issues individual queries but that the driver creates a batch version of this (which is the case with for instance MySQL).

Comment: ALso please add your actual configuration, instead of a description of it.

Comment: @M.Deinum i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable batching in your `application.properties`. Here an example for a batch size of 10.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
```

//Edit: I just saw that you're already setting this property. Try also adding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true`, so that Hibernate can reorder your inserts as needed

Comment: I tried to add what you suggested, it doesn't work